# Move element of a 3d array to the beginning and shift the other values till it reaches the to moving elments place

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've been trying to find a way to move a element of a 3d array-like `int[][][] test = new int[4][5][2]` or `int[][][] test = new int[3][3][1]`. let's say I have the indices of the moving value. Now I want to move the value to the very first position [0][0][0]. And all the other positions go one up till it reaches the indices of the moving value. All values behind that are left untouched. It's important to know that the size of the 3d array can vary strongly. So in a 1d array, it looks something like that `{1,2,3,4,5}` and we want to move the position with the index 2. After the swap, it should look like that `{3,1,2,4,5}`

Comment: When test = `{1, 3, 4}{2, 7, 9}{12, 8, 9}` how should the array look at the end? 
You example is just for an 1d array.

Comment: lets say I wanna move indices i = 1 and j = 2; for this 2d array. then It should look like: `{9 ,1 ,3 },{4 ,2 ,7 },{12 ,8 ,9 }`

Comment: So act like the arrays are just on array?
If you wanna be more efficient it is better to work with List or something else.
I think a ArrayList would work best for your purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an for loop and save the vaule in an temporarily in var.
example code for 1d array scalable:

```
int tmp = test[x];
int tmp2;
for(int i = x; i > 0; i--)
    test[i] = test[i - 1]; 
test[0] = tmp;
```

The element at postion x will be at test[0] and all elements before x shifted by one.

Comment: that doesn't work. because if I change the i+1 with the current value then the next value will be the value from before